# Excel 2016: Return total quantity of matching part #s over multiple lines if conditions are met

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have 1 sheet that needs to get a total quantity of a part number from a 2nd sheet based on if other columns in the second sheet meet specific criteria.

Here is an example:

[image: Sheet 1]

[image: Sheet 2]

And I am trying to use this formula, but only get 0.

```
=IF(OR('SHEET2'!C:C="W", LEFT(TRIM('SHEET2'!D:D),1)="W",LEFT(TRIM('SHEET2'!D:D),1)="5"),SUMIF('SHEET2'!A:A,'SHEET1'!A:A,'SHEET2'!E:E),0)
```

Comment: One approach could be to use a Helper column putting the result of individual OR condition (Col C = W or 1st letter of Col D either W or 5) TRUE / FALSE and then using SUMIFS based on that OR result to keep it simple

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with your range notation.

The formula is looking for products in stockroom W or a bin beginning with 5 or W on the *same* *row* that the formula is entered, *regardless* of the product number on that row.

For example, on Sheet1 for product number 9900400 the formula in B2 checks for the correct stockroom/bin on row 2 of Sheet2. None of the requirements are met so it evaluates to 0. However, if one of the requirements *had* been met it would have reported the total for 9900400, even if 9900400 is not in stockroom W or bin 5/W.

The easiest way to fix this is to make sure all Part #'s are on the same row in both sheets.